# CouchDB view, filtering with array keys

Tags: nosql, mapreduce, couchdb

I am emitting an array-based key with 2 items, for reducing I am just using the built in `_count` function.

```
function (doc) {
  emit([ doc.Name, doc.Date], null); 
}
```

I want to filter by doc.Date while grouping for the count based only on doc.Name (group level 1), e.g between Jan 1st 2010 and Jan 1st 2011,

```
/_view/test?group_level=1&startkey=[{},20100101]&endkey=[{},20110101]
```

However the syntax I am using above doesn't seem to work. There are no results returned. I was under the impression that the {} placeholder is used to match to any key. If I enter a specific document name it works but filters only to that document name,

```
/_view/test?group_level=1&startkey=["MYDOC",20100101]&endkey=["MYDOC",20110101]
```

which comes out,

```
{"rows":[
  {"key":["MYDOC"],"value":10}
]}
```

I do not want to filter at all on the document name, only on the underlying date range. Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you can't just flip your `Name` and `Date` fields in the view output? The way sorting/filtering (such as with startkey/endkey) relies heavily on the order of the keys so it can be fast.

Comment: I want to group by name only. Thus, if name is the first element in the key array, at group_level=1 it is grouped correctly. If date were first, then group_level=1 would group by date only. Apparently this actually isn't supported in couchDB so I'll find a work-around.

Comment: Best workaround will probably be a list function to perform post-query processing like this.

Comment: What do you mean by "based only"? Do you mean that the timespan should be different for the selection and for the count?